# How to repeat first line of file to all first columns?

Tags: csv, awk, sed

I have a file like this :

```
Tax: FOO BAR BAR 
MQ 292018,794;7841123,751;97,000
MQ 293930,660;7841868,082;95,000
MQ 295908,118;7842349,097;93,000
```

I would like to change in this:

```
Tax: FOO BAR BAR;MQ 292018,794;7841123,751;97,000
Tax: FOO BAR BAR;MQ 293930,660;7841868,082;95,000
Tax: FOO BAR BAR;MQ 295908,118;7842349,097;93,000
```

I thinking to use SED or AWK , to do it. Anyone has a idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

awk one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==1{a=$0;next}{print a";"$0}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can grab the first line with `head` and then use `sed` to delete the first line and add the first line content to the beginning of the rest of the lines:

```
first_line=$(head -1 file)
sed "1d;s/^/$first_line;/" file > file.modified
```

Comment: You need to escape the `&` plus the sequences `\1`. `\2` and so on from `$first_line`. Otherwise sed may raise a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
sed '1{h;d;};G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/' file
```